# ng-class doesn't work properly for selected checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, ng-class

I faced with a small problem related with ng-class. I have a list of checkboxes. For this list, I setup ng-class next way, if checkbox selected, set custom css class for selected item. Also I have a checkbox "Select All ", if I click on this box, css class applied for all items, but when I deselect all, css class doesn't change for items which been selected manually before.

I created [**plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/RJ7pyhLJEFPSlGBC8HoV?p=preview) to show my problem.

What am I missing and where is my mistake? Thanks in advance.

html

```
  <table class="table table-hover">
    <tr ng-class="{'selected': allCategoriesSelected, 'default': !allCategoriesSelected}">
        <td class="col-md-2">
            <input type="checkbox"  ng-click="selectAllCategories()" >
        </td>
        <td class="col-md-10" ng-if="!allCategoriesSelected">Select all</td>
        <td class="col-md-10" ng-if="allCategoriesSelected">Deselect all</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="category in categories | orderBy : 'id'" ng-class="{'selected': allCategoriesSelected, 'default': !allCategoriesSelected}" >
        <td class="col-md-2">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="allCategoriesSelected"  ng-click="updateCategory(category.id)">
        </td>
        <td class="col-md-10">{{ category.name }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

js

```
$scope.selectedCategories = [];
$scope.allCategoriesSelected = false;
$scope.selectAllCategories = function() {

  $scope.allCategoriesSelected = !$scope.allCategoriesSelected;

};
$scope.updateCategory = function(categoryId) {

  if ($scope.selectedCategories.indexOf(categoryId) > -1) {
    $scope.selectedCategories.splice($scope.selectedCategories.indexOf(categoryId), 1);

  } else {
    $scope.selectedCategories.push(categoryId);
  }
};
```

Comment: the plunker has another problem: if you select a single category and then select all categories, the class is correctly set but the checkboxes are not checked. is a problem only of the plunker or is a problem also in your code?

Comment: @Jon_Snow fixed plunker

Comment: Do you want the items that were previously selected to become unchecked when clicking "Deselect All" or do you only want the class to change?

Comment: @JoelCDoyle  I want that the items, which been previously selected, became unchecked together with class by click "Deselect All"

Answer (score 0):

I think you are making it too complicated. This can be easily solved with much less code. Here is a working plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/xJz8pdRa4CBWUbdeYbyk?p=preview

Instead of trying to make a separate array to keep track of selected items, just set selected property on categories array.

```
  <table class="table table-hover">
    <tr ng-class="{'selected': allCategoriesSelected, 'default': !allCategoriesSelected}">
        <td class="col-md-2">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="allCategoriesSelected" ng-click="selectAllCategories()" >
        </td>
        <td class="col-md-10" ng-if="!allCategoriesSelected">Select all</td>
        <td class="col-md-10" ng-if="allCategoriesSelected">Deselect all</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="category in categories | orderBy : 'id'" ng-class="{'selected': category.selected}" >
        <td class="col-md-2">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="category.selected">
        </td>
        <td class="col-md-10">{{ category.name }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Changing the markup above, allows this to be accomplished with only one method.

```
  $scope.allCategoriesSelected = false;

  $scope.selectAllCategories = function () {
    var selected = $scope.allCategoriesSelected ? true : false;
    angular.forEach($scope.categories, function(category) {
      category.selected = selected;
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](https://plnkr.co/edit/U8Nio3HzhZudEW2NYLZ8?p=preview) plunker, it should work.

This is the controller :

```
$scope.selectAllCategories = function () {

              if(!$scope.allCategoriesSelected) $scope.setAll(false);
              else $scope.setAll(true);

            };
            $scope.updateCategory = function () {
              if($scope.checkedAll()) $scope.allCategoriesSelected = true;
              else $scope.allCategoriesSelected = false;
            };

            $scope.checkedAll = function(){
              var ret = true;
              $scope.categories.forEach(function(item){
                if(!item.selected) ret = ret && false;
              });
              console.log(ret);
              return ret;
            }

            $scope.setAll = function(state){
              $scope.categories.forEach(function(item){
                item.selected = state;
              });
            }
```